# Setting up default input device in Ubuntu 18.04 by using PyAudio

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, pyaudio

I'm writing a program to take voice input from the built in microphone and then print the received voice on screen. My program is as follows :

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything :")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said : {}".format(text))
    except:
        print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")
```

but I'm getting the error as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text.py", line 4, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/home/ashish/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 86, in __init__
    device_info = audio.get_device_info_by_index(device_index) if device_index is not None else audio.get_default_input_device_info()
  File "/home/ashish/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 949, in get_default_input_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Raspberry Pi board, you’ll need a USB sound card (or USB microphone).

Once you do this, change all instances of Microphone() to Microphone(device_index=MICROPHONE_INDEX), where MICROPHONE_INDEX is the hardware-specific index of the microphone.

To hack on this library, first make sure you have all the requirements listed in the “Requirements” section.

-Most of the library code lives in speech_recognition/**init**.py.

- Examples live under the examples/ [directory](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/tree/master/examples), and the demo script lives in speech_recognition/**main**.py.
- The FLAC encoder binaries are in the speech_recognition/ [directory](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/tree/master/speech_recognition).
- Documentation can be found in the reference/ [directory](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/tree/master/reference).

To run all the tests:

```
python -m unittest discover --verbose code here
```

Comment: Is there anything in the question specifying Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I'm not using Raspberry Pi. I'm simply using laptop with ubuntu 18.04 OS on it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Anaconda's problem.
`conda install pyaudio` works well for me on Windows 10, however, it gives me the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04. It's fixed by reinstalling pyaudio from pip.

```
conda remove pyaudio
conda remove portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

Note that you have to remove both pyaudio and portaudio.

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/4139